# Set custom position to the calendar with position:fixed

Tags: react-datepicker

I use react-date-picker and want to show the popuped calendar over the modal. When I set the new styles for position:fixed, top and left in onCalendarOpen() it works properly and set the position where I want. But when I close the calendar and open again my styles are overrided by the framework's default styles.

Thanks in advance!